# create custom tab in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

i am  trying to create custom tab in android , i have create the Tabs into `FragmentActivity` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Here is the code of but i really don't know where do i inflate the custom tabs using

```
View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).
                   inflate(R.layout.tab_item, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
```

code in onCreate method of FragmentActivity

```
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        if(mTabHost!=null) System.out.println("***ITS NOT NULL****");

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                ContactSummaryFragment.class, null);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Template"),
                TextVoiceTemplate.class, null);
```

addTab method

```
  public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
                tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));

       // I got to place this line somewhere here i guess
                //View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_item, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
                String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

                TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
                mTabs.add(info);
                mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify your layout with tabSpec:

Here you have addTab in your adapter

```
    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
            {
                tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
                String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

                TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
                mTabs.add(info);
                mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

and before you fill you tab with content (ususally in onCreate) you can write your own function

```
private static View prepareTabView(Context context, String text, int drawable)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabTitle)).setText(text);
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabImage)).setImageResource(drawable);
        return view;

    }

    public static void addTab(TabsAdapter adapter, TabHost host, String title, String tag, int drawable, Class cl)
    {   
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec(tag);
        View view = prepareTabView(host.getContext(), title, drawable);
        spec.setIndicator(view);

        adapter.addTab(spec, cl,null);

    }
```

and now you can populate your tabHost with your own addTab, that uses addTab in adapter:

```
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager, getSupportFragmentManager());

        addTab(mTabsAdapter, mTabHost, getString(R.string.title1), CONST, R.drawable.tab_drawable1, Fragment1.class);
        addTab(mTabsAdapter, mTabHost, getString(R.string.title1), CONST2, R.drawable.tab_formula_image_selector, Fragment2.class);
```

in this example you have R.layout.tab_layout with drawable, background, text and etc... :

R.layout.tab_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top" android:background="@drawable/tabbg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/tabtextcolor"
        android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_above="@id/tabTitle" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

with this example you will have smth like this:

[image: Sample result]

Comment: this is a factory from android-sdks\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos\src\com\example\android\supportv4\app\FragmentTabsPager.java