# How to use custom iPhone tab in FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

I am new in Android and I tried to create a tab using FragmentActivity from codes that I found online. 
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

This is my FragmentActivity http://pastie.org/pastes/5170802/text?key=jhowuevxe2fshlwu5tisg

I would like to use a custom layout that uses an image and text.

```
//tab_indicator.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="55dip"    
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I found a similar question here : [create custom tab in FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958303/create-custom-tab-in-fragmentactivity) but I couldn't figure it out how to apply the solution in my codes. Can someone teach me how? Thank you.

Update:

I managed to inflate the custom layout in my codes. But I faced another error. This is my latest codes http://pastie.org/pastes/5187362/text?key=74r87diquysvruwsam1tq tweaked to FragmentActivity, from AdilSoomro http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html codes (which uses TabActivity) with some references from

- http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/
- http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

My latest codes successfully inflate the layout like this, with the setting http://pastie.org/pastes/5187408/text?key=qxxa5xxrhsburebllyhmw for its layout (tab_indicator.xml)

[image]
but I need to align my tab to the bottom. When I align it to the bottom, the code layout_gravity="bottom" worked on Graphical Layout but when I run it, my relative layout's background fill the whole screen, like this with the code http://pastie.org/pastes/5187445/text?key=6dz2tsiggey9se51d2thtq

[image]

can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: where did you get problem in above reference code which you share here.

Comment: @chintankhetiya i have no idea where to inflate my layout in my codes. i'm new in this so rather blur with using fragments.

Comment: @chintankhetiya hey i managed to inflate my layout in the codes but, when i moved the bar to the bottom, the background fills the page. but when i preview it in Graphical Layout, the background does not fill the page. Let me paste some image and my layout codes

Comment: BTW, using design patterns of other OSs is not a good practice. See: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: yeap @C.d. i am aware of that, which is why I was struggling with it, and very hard to get resources for it, but my project requires me to do so. I couldn't run away from it as there are requirements that I have to meet. But thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Finally! After testing other resources that I referred to, I realized that layout_alignParentBottom in RelativeLayout does not give any outcome. Hence I tried aligning the TabWidget to the bottom instead, and it worked!

This is my main.xml that contain TabHost and TabWidget.
http://pastie.org/pastes/5188297/text?key=lqfp3jnofs5kgsvslm3yg

Keep the tab_indicator.xml / the settings for the text and image like this : http://pastie.org/pastes/5187408/text?key=qxxa5xxrhsburebllyhmw

And here is the a custom iPhone tab that uses FragmentActivity :

P/S : Sorry if my Java file is confusing, I'm new and if there is anything I did wrong, do tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this Honey >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"    
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
    android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
    android:padding="5dp"> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tested my codes in a different file. it is supposed to align below. my guess is that, there may be a problem with my java code