# ActionBarSherlock with translucent tab navigation

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

In my app I have ActionBar with tabs and I want to make tabs translucent, but not ActionBar. Is it possible to achive this via styles and themes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom layout and inflate it to use it as tabs

Please find it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013297/951045

and to hide actionbar use 
         getSupportActionBar().hide(); // if you are using support lib 
       otherwise use  getActionBar().hide();

You can also hide actionbar by using Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar (for support lib)